# Magento 2:Icon on hover

Tags: magento-2.1, addtocart

In my category listing page, I want to show 'Add to Cart',Add to Wishlist,Add to Compare on product hover. Any idea to show an icon on product hover in list page.Please help .Thanks in advance.

http://i.prntscr.com/042f9bda611d489ea4d188c41607e147.png